# Heroku Login Error in Git Bash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, bash, heroku

In Git Bash, it does not recognize the file or directory. I also have Ruby 1.9.3 installed but the output is showing 1.9.2

$ heroku login

/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku: line 4: /c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.
2/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
/c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/bin/heroku: line 4: exec: /c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/rub
y-1.9.2/bin/ruby: cannot execute: No such file or directory

Should I uninstall Heroku Toolbelt and reinstall or is there a fix to the two problems I am having?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, it's a bit hard to figure out what you're trying to say. Are you saying that you run `heroku login` on a bash-terminal and it's giving you that error message? What happens when you try `ruby -v`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the shebang directive `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` of the [`bin/heroku`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/bin/heroku) script resolves 'ruby':

- as `/c/.../bin/ruby`
- instead of `/c/.../bin/ruby.exe`

That means it cannot call "`ruby`" on Windows because that file doesn't exist ("`ruby.exe`" does).

As a workaround (to see if that resolves the issue),

- copy /c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe
- to /c/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/ruby-1.9.2/bin/ruby

(check the protection of that file: it should be executable by default)

Make sure that `ruby -v` does work (meaning your `$PATH` in the bash shell does include `bin/ruby`)